# What is the Moduli Space, and why do we care about it?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, moduli

1. What is the [moduli space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_%28physics%29) of a QFT?
2. What does it mean exactly that there are different inequivalent vacua?
3. Can someone give a precise definition of the moduli space, and some easy examples?
4. And why is it so important and studied nowadays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be useful to migrate questions 1,3 to math.SE; as for the mathematical side of the story, I think that all gravitates around the idea of moduli space (a *modulus* being -as far as I know- the old name for "the set of values a certain variable takes as soon as it runs over a certain set (often a continuum)").

The idea of a "moduli problem" is central to modern Algebraic Geometry, and it is deeply intertwined with Physics: I am not an expert on the second field, but I can give a (fairly heuristic) idea of the first. You will realize in a while that the topic is really huge; all that follows is not intended to strive for rigor.

The rough idea is fairly simple, indeed. As a starting example consider the generic conic in the projective plane $\mathbb P^2(k)$; as you may know, such a geometric locus is the zero-set of a polynomial which depends on a certain set of coefficients: more precisely, you have to consider the polynomial
$$
a X_0^2 + 2 b X_0 X_1 + 2 c X_0 X_2 + d X_1^2 + 2 e X_1X_2 + f X_2^2=0
$$
where $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ can on its own right be identified to a point of the projective space $\mathbb P^5(k)$. And non-degenerate conics, i.e. those conics whose matrix has nonzero determinant, can be identified with an hypersurface in $\mathbb P^5(k)$.

This identification is the key-step in understanding the definition of moduli space: *a set of geometric objects can often be regarded as a geometric object of the same kind.*

Now that you have your moduli-glasses on, you will notice that lots of things are indeed moduli spaces: the set of nondegenerate conics in the projective plane happens to be a cubic hypersurface; the set of iso classes of vector bundles over a given manifold can be thought as a space on its own right; and in the same vein, for example, there are cases when the set of degree-zero complex line bundles over a smooth projective curve is not only a group (the *Picard* group $Pic^0(\mathcal C)$ of the curve $\cal C$) but also a complex torus (this is an old theorem due to Jacobi).

The formalism of moduli problems offers you a way to express this in full generality: to formulate a "moduli problem" you need the following gadgets.

1. A class of geometric objects (if this is not painful, think of it as a category $\cal A$ of spaces -manifolds, bundles, Lie groups,...-)
2. A rule which assigns to every space $S$ an $S$-parametric family of objects, i.e. a bundle of $\cal A$-objects. In other words, you want to give a function $\rho\colon s\in S\mapsto F_s\in \cal A$: in the case where $\cal A=$manifolds, any space $X$ gives rise to such a structure, taking as $\rho$ a rule which assigns to every $s\in S$ a bundle $F_s\to X$ over $X$.
3. The assignment $\rho=\rho_S$ has to be functorial and contravariant in $S$, namely any transformation $S\to T$ must induce a morphism between the bundle $F'$ of $T$-parametric objects and the bundle $F$ of $S$-parametric object; again in the case of bundles over a manifold, this is given by pull-back operation.

To package all this stuff in a single, nifty request: we would like to have a *contravariant functor* ${\cal A}\to Set$ which sends an object $S$ to the set of all $S$-parametric objects $F_*=\{F_s\}_s$ of $\cal A$: understanding this functor is your moduli problem.

This is the place where a key step for the *solution* of your moduli problem comes into play: denote this functor as $\Phi$ and suppose you can find a space $M\in\cal A$ such that $$\Phi(S)\cong {\rm Map}(S,M);$$ this request is not so absurd, since for example you can impose $M=Ob(\cal A)$ endowed with a suitable topology, and define a map of sets $F_*\mapsto (s\mapsto F_s)$. This map is *natural* in $S$, so that if $M$ exists, then it is unique up to a unique isomorphism in $\cal A$. In a more categorical jargon, the functor $\Phi$ is *represented* by the space $M$, which is called the (fine) *moduli space* of your moduli problem.

The problem is that moduli problems are seldom solvable (if all of them were, Algebraic Geometry would be far more easy; it's up to you to decide if this is a good thing)! In most cases of interest *no moduli space exists*, in the fine sense. To workaround this problem, one needs to define a *coarse* notion of solution for a moduli problem, but this would turn out to be too technical, and I think I've been far too verbose for a single response.

Instead I would try to sum up: often in geometry you have to cope with families of spaces which can be turned into another space, called the moduli space of the family: each point in the moduli space corresponds to a space on its own right. The geometry of the moduli space tells you things about the geometry of the spaces/points in it. This is precisely what I read when I see

> the space of vacua for the quantum field theory is a manifold (or orbifold), usually called the vacuum manifold. This manifold is often called the moduli space of vacua, or just the moduli space, for short.